# How to host ASP.NET Web Pages w/ Razor Under Wordpress?

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, razor, url-rewrite-module

The Problem
When I try to get to my ASP.NET Web Page Razor pages using the cshtml extension, they work fine. If I remove the extension, WordPress tries to look up the URL as if it were a blog post and I can't get to the page or use "pretty" URLs via Razor.

I am hosting with Winhost. I have WordPress installed in my root application directory. That directory contains the following Web.cofig file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="index.php"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
                <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*"/>
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                        </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
                </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My application is in the sub-folder "/app". You can test out the problem yourself by going here:

http://www.cutrategamer.com/app/game-deals-chart.cshtml

Then try going here:

http://www.cutrategamer.com/app/game-deals-chart/

The page works fine without the cshtml extension on my local machine.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the **wordpress** rule, add a rule to catch the **/app** traffic and stop processing rules, something like this:

```
<rule name="razorapp" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^app/*"/>
    <action type="None" />
</rule>
```

Not sure if that is exactly correct, but you should get the idea.  You need to short circuit the rewrite module before it processes the **wordpress** rule in your config.

Comment: That was what was missing. Thanks Paul!